# Best practice for storing a user's ppk file in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I need to connect to SFTP from  lambda function in node.js.

```
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');

const config = {
host: 'host',
port: 22,
username: 'user',
privateKey: 'location of privatekey file',
password: 'passphrase'
};
```

I will access the passphrase from SecretsManager. My first thought was to store the ppk file (encrypted) in an AWS S3 bucket. I have looked to see if there is a best practice for storing and retrieving ppk files from AWS, but couldn't find anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This AWS blog post may assist: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-manager-securely-store-rotate-ssh-key-pairs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea sounds good.

But instead you could encrypt the s3 files with kms and give the lambda functions the permission to decrypt the files. Sounds less a hussle to me than encrypting the files manually and storing the password somewhere.

See the official documentation for more informations: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-s3.html

Comment: That was the plan if I went the S3 route. Thanks!